# Yahoo Finance V7 API now requiring cookies? (Python)

Tags: python, cookies, python-requests, yahoo-finance

```
url = 'https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/quote?symbols=TSLA&fields=regularMarketPreviousClose&region=US&lang=en-US'
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
}
data = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
prepost_data = data.json()
```

It seems recently, Yahoo Finance changed their V7 API to require cookies for every request. Running the code above, I get the Invalid Crumb error

`{"finance":{"result":null,"error":{"code":"Unauthorized","description":"Invalid Crumb"}}}`

This issue seems to also be known in this Github repo: https://github.com/joshuaulrich/quantmod/issues/382

They seem to have a patch that works: https://github.com/joshuaulrich/quantmod/pull/383/commits

But the code is all written in R... Anyone know how to translate this to Python?

Comment: Running your code I get normal Json response `{'quoteResponse': {'result': [{'language': 'en-US', 'region': 'US', 'quoteType': 'EQUITY', ...`

Comment: @AndrejKesely Yeah it seems they fixed it overnight. I guess my question now is should I be including cookies in my headers? If so, what is the best way to do that?

Comment: Have you found a fix for this? I use an application that updates stock prices using that API, and it's been broken for a few weeks now.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This worked for me.

1. Make HTTP GET call to URL https://fc.yahoo.com. Although this call result in a 404 error, we just need it to extract `set-cookie` from response headers which is then used in the subsequent calls
2. Now make an HTTP GET call to the URL https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v1/test/getcrumb, by including the obtained cookie from the previous response headers. This call will retrieve the crumb value.
3. Replace `[crumb-value]` in the following URL and make a HTTP GET call with cookie [https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/quote?symbols=TSLA&crumb=[crumb-value]](https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/quote?symbols=TSLA&crumb=%5Bcrumb-value%5D)
4. Cache the cookie value and crumb value to skip first two steps going forward

Comment: Thanks, I was able to do this as well.

Comment: `set-cookie` isn't in the response headers anymore for step #1. Can anyone else verify?

Comment: @HBCondo For me, the "set-cookie" is still present in the response headers.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a sample Python code based on the answer from @mahindar to get the cookie and crumb:

```
import requests


def get_yahoo_cookie():
    cookie = None

    user_agent_key = "User-Agent"
    user_agent_value = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36"

    headers = {user_agent_key: user_agent_value}
    response = requests.get(
        "https://fc.yahoo.com", headers=headers, allow_redirects=True
    )

    if not response.cookies:
        raise Exception("Failed to obtain Yahoo auth cookie.")

    cookie = list(response.cookies)[0]

    return cookie


def get_yahoo_crumb(cookie):
    crumb = None

    user_agent_key = "User-Agent"
    user_agent_value = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36"

    headers = {user_agent_key: user_agent_value}

    crumb_response = requests.get(
        "https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v1/test/getcrumb",
        headers=headers,
        cookies={cookie.name: cookie.value},
        allow_redirects=True,
    )
    crumb = crumb_response.text

    if crumb is None:
        raise Exception("Failed to retrieve Yahoo crumb.")

    return crumb


# Usage
cookie = get_yahoo_cookie()
crumb = get_yahoo_crumb(cookie)
```

Answer (score 2):

I did in php, the code is:

```
<?php

/* 1 - Get cookie */
//https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76065035/yahoo-finance-v7-api-now-requiring-cookies-python
$url_yahoo = "https://fc.yahoo.com";
$yahoo_headers = get_headers($url_yahoo, true);
//print_r($yahoo_headers);
$cookie_name = 'Set-Cookie';

/* 2 - Get crumb , setting cookie */
$url_yahoo2 = "https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v1/test/getcrumb";
$c = curl_init($url_yahoo2);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $yahoo_headers[$cookie_name]);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$crumb = curl_exec($c);
curl_close($c);
//echo "<BR>Crumb:" . $crumb;

/* 3 - Get quotes with crumb, setting cookie. Using sample tickets*/
$tickets_list = "AAPL,TSLA";
$url_cotacao = "https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/quote?symbols=" . $tickets_list . "&crumb=" . $crumb;
$c = curl_init($url_cotacao);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $yahoo_headers[$cookie_name]);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$data_quote = curl_exec($c);
curl_close($c);


/* 4 - Get data from yahoo */
$resJson_decode = json_decode($data_quote, false);
if (!$resJson_decode->quoteResponse->result) {
    $resultado = "Ticket dont exists in yahoo!";
} else {
    foreach ($resJson_decode->quoteResponse->result as $ticket_result){
        echo "<BR>Ticket:" . $ticket_result->symbol;
        echo "<BR>Price:" . $ticket_result->regularMarketPrice;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: But the question is for Python.

Answer (score 2):

For completion let me add a JavaScript version. I was researching this problem quite a bit and I am astonished how simple the solution finally is.
Alternatively, cookie and crumb can also be obtained and extracted from finance.yahoo.com

```js
const API = 'https://query2.finance.yahoo.com'

async function getCredentials() {
  // get the A3 cookie
  const { headers } = await fetch('https://fc.yahoo.com')
  const cookie = headers.get('set-cookie')
  // now get the crumb
  const url = new URL('/v1/test/getcrumb', API)
  const request = new Request(url)
  request.headers.set('cookie', cookie)
  const response = await fetch(request)
  const crumb = await response.text()
  return { cookie, crumb } 
}

async function quote(symbols, cookie, crumb) {
  const url = new URL('v7/finance/quote', API)
  url.searchParams.set('symbols', symbols.join(','))
  url.searchParams.set('crumb', crumb)
  const request = new Request(url)
  request.headers.set('cookie', cookie)
  const response = await fetch(request)
  const {quoteResponse} = await response.json()
  return quoteResponse?.result || []
}

// main
const { cookie, crumb } = await getCredentials()
const quotes = await quote(['GOOG', 'TSLA'], cookie, crumb)
if (quotes.length) {
  for (const quote of quotes) {
    console.log(`${quote.symbol} price is ${quote.currency} ${quote.regularMarketPrice}`)
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain how OP would use your code in their Python script?

Comment: It's possible to call node from python, the code provided above is for Node.js.
For use in Python just adapt the code. It turns out that Pyhton requests and responses have a cookies property which is convenient. Python version follows below:

Comment: Thanks for writing an answer... and another answer. Usually it's best to answer in a way OP can use the code in the answer as a drop-in replacement. Explanations are a must for great answers. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 2):

```py
import requests

apiBase = 'https://query2.finance.yahoo.com'
headers = { 
  "User-Agent": 
  "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64)"
}

def getCredentials(cookieUrl='https://fc.yahoo.com', crumbUrl=apiBase+'/v1/test/getcrumb'):
  cookie = requests.get(cookieUrl).cookies
  crumb = requests.get(url=crumbUrl, cookies=cookie, headers=headers).text
  return {'cookie': cookie, 'crumb': crumb}

def quote(symbols, credentials):
  url = apiBase + '/v7/finance/quote'
  params = {'symbols': ','.join(symbols), 'crumb': credentials['crumb']}
  response = requests.get(url, params=params, cookies=credentials['cookie'], headers=headers)
  quotes = response.json()['quoteResponse']['result']
  return quotes

credentials = getCredentials()
quotes = quote(['GOOG', 'TSLA'], credentials)
if quotes:
  for quote in quotes:
    print(f"{quote['symbol']} price is {quote['currency']} {quote['regularMarketPrice']}")

# GOOG price is USD 121.08
# TSLA price is USD 256.24
```

I used https://www.codeconvert.ai/javascript-to-python-converter plus some modifications

Answer (score 2):

Based on the other answers (a big thank you to the contributors!) I was able to update my Excel VBA code which now works again (question is: how long...).

Here is the complete solution which also includes how to retrieve the cookie from the header as `http.getResponseHeader "set-cookie"` doesn't yield anything in VBA (question from @HBCondo). The cookie and crumb are requested only once and stored in global variables. No check for validity has been added so far although the cookie expires after a certain time. ParseJson is a function in the VBA-JSON project available on Github.

```
Public crumb As String
Public cookie As String

Public Sub YahooGetCrumb()
    Dim http As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Dim strHeader As String
    Dim strFields() As String
    
    Set http = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    
    http.Open "GET", "https://fc.yahoo.com"
    http.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36"
    http.send
    
    strHeader = http.getAllResponseHeaders
    strFields = Split(strHeader, vbCrLf)
    cookie = Trim(Split(Split(strFields(5), ";")(0), ":")(1)) & "; " & Trim(Split(Split(strFields(6), ";")(0), ":")(1))

    http.Open "GET", "https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v1/test/getcrumb"
    http.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36"
    http.setRequestHeader "Cookie", cookie
    http.send
    
    crumb = http.responseText
    
End Sub

Public Function GetYahooData(sSymbol As String) As String
    Dim http As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    
    If crumb = "" Then
        YahooGetCrumb
    End If
    
    Set http = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    
    http.Open "GET", "https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/quote?symbols=" & sSymbol & "&crumb=" & crumb, False
    http.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36"
    http.send
    
    GetYahooData = http.responseText
    
End Function

Public Sub test()
    Dim JSON As Object

    responseText = GetYahooData("AAPL")
    
    Set JSON = ParseJson(responseText)
end Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

**PowerShell Usage Example :**

```
    # ► Create $session Object
$session = New-Object Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebRequestSession
$Stock = "MSFT" 

    # ► Call 1st Url ( Gain some headers and cookies stuff ) - using try & catch to prevent 404 error ( as mentioned above )
try { Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing -Uri "https://fc.yahoo.com/" -SessionVariable session } catch {
  $null}        
        

    # ► Call 2nd Url ( Generate Crumb ) 
$crumb = Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing -Uri "https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v1/test/getcrumb" -WebSession $session


    # ► Call 3rd Url ( Get Yahoo's Data ) 
$URL = $("https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v10/finance/quoteSummary/" + $Stock + "?modules=price&crumb=" + $crumb)
$ResponseText = Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing -Uri $URL -WebSession $session

    
    # ► Print Result
$ResponseText = $ResponseText.ToString()
$ResponseText
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this for VBA macro:

```js
Public Function GetStockData() As String
    Dim qurl As String
    Dim cookie As String
    Dim crumb As String
    Dim req As Object
    Dim cookieurl As String

    cookieurl = "https://fc.yahoo.com" 'This page needs to return a cookie, query1.finance.yahoo does not return cookie.
    
    Set req = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
    
    'get cookie
    With req
        .Open "GET", cookieurl, False
        .setRequestHeader "REFERER", cookieurl
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
        .Send
        
        cookie = .getResponseHeader("Set-Cookie") 'gets cookie and saves it.
    End With
   
    'get crumb
    With req
        .Open "GET", "https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v1/test/getcrumb", False 'gets crumb, which must be attached to all quote calls
        .setRequestHeader "REFERER", cookieurl
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
        .setRequestHeader "Cookie", cookie 'applies cookie to header, currently working without this, but probably good practice to use it
        .Send
        
        crumb = .responseText 'saves crumb
    End With
    
    qurl = "http://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/quote?symbols=AAPL"
  
    qurl = qurl & "&crumb=" & crumb 'add crumb info from GetCookie sub
    

    'get data
    With req
        .Open "GET", qurl, False
        'header is needed but not specific, could probbaly remove a couple lines without creating a problem
        .setRequestHeader "REFERER", cookieurl
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
        .setRequestHeader "Cookie", cookie
        .Send
        GetStockData = .responseText 'get data and return
    End With
End Function
```